# spark df.write.partitionBy run very slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame that when saved as Parquet format takes ~11GB.
When reading to a dataframe and writing to json, it takes 5 minutes.
When I add partitionBy("day") it takes hours to finish.
I understand that the distribution to partitions is the costly action. 
Is there a way to make it faster? Will sorting the files can make it better?

Example:

**Run 5 minutes**

```
df=spark.read.parquet(source_path).
df.write.json(output_path)
```

**Run for hours**

```
spark.read.parquet(source_path).createOrReplaceTempView("source_table")
sql="""
select cast(trunc(date,'yyyymmdd') as int) as day, a.*
from source_table a"""
spark.sql(sql).write.partitionBy("day").json(output_path)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding a `repartition("day")` before the `write`, like this:

```
spark
  .sql(sql)
  .repartition("day")
  .write
  .partitionBy("day")
  .json(output_path)
```

It should speed up your query.

Comment: Thanks!!!  That worked, I just had to do it with $ sign before the day: .repartition($"day")

Comment: I had the same problem and this also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding repartition(any number ) to start with, then try increasing / decreasing the number depending upon the time it takes to write

```
 spark
  .sql(sql)
  .repartition(any number)
  .write
  .partitionBy("day")
  .json(output_path)
```